# TypeScript with passport-local: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I'm trying to use the `passport-local` package with TypeScript (2.0.0RC) but I'm getting a compiler error stating:

> error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Screenshot of this in VS Code attached (the code under the tooltip is just `passport.use(`).

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to give it the signature it wants.

I found a [few](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2081) [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1946) on the topic, but anything I try just gives other compiler errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to make the compiler happy with this code?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the typings for `passport-local`, but   `new localStrategy.Strategy( ...`  might work.

Comment: That was it! Doh - I feel like a proper muppet. Thanks for taking the tme to point that out!

Comment: The easy fix would be to change your import statement. Try "import {Strategy as localStrategy} from 'passport-local'. Then your `new localStrategy` will work fine.

Answer (score 32):

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this one:

```
import * as passportLocal from 'passport-local';
const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as PassportGoogle from "passport-google-oauth2";

passport.use(
  new PassportGoogle.Strategy(
 {
  clientID: "",
  clientSecret: "",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/google/callback",
  passReqToCallback: true,
},
function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

  }
 )
);
```